# WPF UserControl fill ContentControl with fixed width and height

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have UserControls that I want to display in a ContentControl. So what I did(this is just one UserControl I have more):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Suburb" DataType="{x:Type local:ViewSuburb}">
        <local:ViewSuburb Width="Auto" Height="Auto" />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Suburb}">
</ContentControl>
```

(The ViewSuburb Width="Auto" Height="Auto" has no effect)

My problem is that the ViewSuburb is only used as a popup dialog thus in its .xaml I gave it a fixed width and height. If I set the width and height to auto then it is fine in the ContentControl and stretches accordingly but it stretches the popup over the screen. Since I gave it the fixed width and height the popup is fine but in the ContentControl it also has the fixed width and height.

Is there a way I can override the width and height of the SuburbView or if I set it to auto that the popup wouldn't stretch across the screen?

Thanks.

Comment: have u tried to set MaxWidth and MaxHeigth on that SuburbView, that way  it wont stretch beyond that max values.

Comment: Yes then it sill has a fixed size in the ContentControl.

Comment: Set the Width/Height of the Popup/Window.

Comment: @mm8 Thanks did the trick can you please give it as an answer so I can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `Width`/`Height` of the `Popup`/`Window` that is the parent of the `ContentControl`.